# Add text to start of multiple files in single sed command

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to add the text `foo` to the start of all files in a certain directory. I tried the following command:

```
sed '1i foo' *
```

But that only added the text to the first file. How can I append to all files in a single `sed` command? (I know that it can be done with a `for` loop, I'm specifically asking for a single `sed` command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use option `--separate` (or short: `-s`) to consider files as separate rather than as a single continuous long stream.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alter the files, just add the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i '1i foo' *
```

It'll add `foo` at the beginning of every file.

Note: without `-i`, the files weren't actually modified. `foo` was added at the beginning of the whole content to the standard output only, thus appearing only once.

Comment: Note that -i / --in-place editing of files via sed is a GNU extension, so this might not work on all Unix platforms.

Comment: This may work, but I explicitly did _not_ include `-i` because I want to test if it works first.

Comment: @finitegraygreen : I didn't know, thanks. For what it's worth, it also works with FreeBSD's sed.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
sed -i '1 s/^/foo/g' *
```